# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_QuoteController::_getSession() in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, quote, phpstorm

I'm new to magento, and My intention is create Request for Quote like [this link](http://demo.cart2quote.com/qquoteadv/index/).So for this I have created the custom module for Request the Quote. In this I have add the Add quote buttons in `\app\design\frontend\mypackage\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Quote') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/quote/index'); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Quote') ?></span></span></button>
```

when customer click on Add to Quote button I redirected/navigated to quote page. So for this I have created QuoteController in `magento\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\QuoteController.php`

```
<?php

class Mage_Checkout_QuoteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    protected function _getCart()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    }

    /**
     * Get current active quote instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    protected function _getQuote()
    {
        return $this->_getCart()->getQuote();
    }

    function indexAction()
    {

      /*  $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Request for Quote'));
        $this->renderLayout();
        Mage::log("Request for quote");*/

      $cart = $this->_getCart();
        if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
            $cart->init();
            $cart->save();

            if (!$this->_getQuote()->validateMinimumAmount()) {
                $minimumAmount = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
                    ->toCurrency(Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount'));

                $warning = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
                    ? Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
                    : Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Minimum order amount is %s', $minimumAmount);

                $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addNotice($warning);
            }
        }

        // Compose array of messages to add
        $messages = array();
        foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getMessages() as $message) {
            if ($message) {
                // Escape HTML entities in quote message to prevent XSS
                $message->setCode(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message->getCode()));
                $messages[] = $message;
            }
        }
        $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addUniqueMessages($messages);

        /**
         * if customer enteres shopping cart we should mark quote
         * as modified bc he can has checkout page in another window.
         */
        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
        $this
            ->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
            ->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Request for Quote'));
        $this->renderLayout();
        Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
    }



    public function sendemailAction()
    {
        //Fetch submited params      

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $to = $params['email'];

        Mage::log((array)$to);

        $sub = 'Test Email From Magento SMTP Pro Module';
        $body = $params['comment'];
        Mage::log((array)$body);

        $mail->addTo($to)
            ->setFrom("dotnet@gmail.com")
            ->setSubject($sub)
            ->setBodyText($body);

        $websiteModel = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'));

        try {
            $transport = Mage::helper('smtppro')->getTransport($websiteModel->getId());

            Mage::log((array)$transport);

            $mail->send($transport);

            Mage::dispatchEvent('smtppro_email_after_send',
                array('to' => $to,
                    'template' => "SMTPPro Self Test",
                    'subject' => $sub,
                    'html' => false,
                    'email_body' => $body));

            $msg =  "<br/> Test email was sent successfully.";
            Mage::log("Test email was sent successfully");


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $success = false;
            $msg = $msg . "<br/> Unable to send test email. Exception message was: " . $e->getMessage() . "...";
            $msg = $msg . "<br/> Please check and double check your username and password.";
            Mage::log("Test email was not sent successfully: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->_redirect("*/quote/index");

    }
}
```

And `app\design\frontend\mypackage\default\layout\checkout.xml` file I have register the my custom file that is `test.phtml` file

```
<checkout_quote_index translate="label">
        <label>Request for quote</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block template="checkout/cart/test.phtml" name="quote" type="checkout/cart_quote"></block>
        </reference>

    </checkout_quote_index>
```

And finally I have displayed the Request for Quote front page as `test.phtml`

```
magento\app\design\frontend\mypackage\default\template\checkout\cart\test.phtml in this I have wrote below code

<div class="cart">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?></h1>
        <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <ul class="checkout-types">
                <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
                    <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
                <col width="1" />
                <col />
                <col width="1" />
                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <col width="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />

                <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"></th>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span></th>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></span></th>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                    <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="50" class="a-right">
                        <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>
                        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                        <input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_container" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
                                {
                                    // Internet Explorer (lt 8) does not support value attribute in button elements
                                    $emptyCartButton = $('empty_cart_button');
                                    $cartActionContainer = $('update_cart_action_container');
                                    if ($emptyCartButton && $cartActionContainer) {
                                        Event.observe($emptyCartButton, 'click', function()
                                        {
                                            $emptyCartButton.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                                            $cartActionContainer.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action');
                                            $cartActionContainer.setValue('empty_cart');
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="cart-collaterals">
        <div class="col2-set">
            <div class="col-1">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
                <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totals">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
            <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
                <ul class="checkout-types">
                    <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                        <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                            <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

finally it's displaying page but this is given an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_QuoteController::_getSession()`

**can tell me where I went wrong or how to implement that functionality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. You are making a call to a method that does not exist.

```
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Either define the method `_getSession` or remove the line I mentioned above if you don't need it.
*Small tip off topic*: Don't add classes to the `core` codepool and don't use the `Mage` namespace. Create your own module under a different namespace in `community` or `local`.

Comment: I know that but this is test after success I will update/move to local. any way thank you :)

Comment: yah! working fine. here actually I copied the code from shopping cart code, If I want to move this to Add Quote module like [this example](http://demo.cart2quote.com/checkout/cart/) here first the item will add the quote after he moves to shopping cart. how can I implement can you suggest/guide me?

Comment: Can you suggest/guide me?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I don't have the specs for your request. You can add an other question, but I'm afraid it will be considered off topic.